# What does (res) => res.json() do in a Promise catch?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm working with this piece of code, and can not really get my head around what's happening :

```
const postDataToAPI = async (path) => {
    return await fetch(`/api${path}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    }).then(function(res) {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error(res);
        }

        return res;

    }).then((res) => res.json());
};
```

So the idea is that I need to check what the response code of a request is. When `!res.ok` then I need to throw an exception.

I don't get how `.then((res) => res.json());` can invoke res.json(), while `new Error(res.json());` fails with `Error: [object Promise]`.

There's clearly something about the `(res) => res.json()` syntax I do not know or understand.

How can I throw an Error containing `res.json()`?

Comment: `res.json()` returns a new promise that must be awaited. Returning a promise from a `.then` awaits that promise. Passing it to `new Error` does not…

Comment: You are mixing `await` style and `.then()` styles together, which is unsettling and messy. Use only `await` (much, much easier to deal with) : `const res = await fetch(...); const data = await res.json();` Job done. Or even `const data = await (await fetch(...)).json();`

Comment: `return await` just like that is an [antipattern](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-await). There is no reason to `await` the return in an async function, unless it is inside a `try ... catch`.

Answer (score 3):

`.then` always returns the promise from the function passed to it. `res.json` returns a promise (don't ask me why). So if you really want to throw an error when the json is parsed, do this:

```js
const postDataToAPI = async (path) => {
    return await fetch(`/api${path}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    }).then(function(res) {
        if (!res.ok) {
            return res.json().then(json => throw new Error(json));
        }

        return res;

    }).then((res) => res.json());
};
```

If you want to merge the two `.then`s you can do this:

```js
const postDataToAPI = async (path) => {
    return await fetch(`/api${path}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    }).then(function(res) {
        if (!res.ok) {
            return res.json().then(json => { throw new Error(json) });
        }

        return res.json();

    });
};
```

To only use async/await you can do this:

```js
const postDataToAPI = async (path) => {
    const res = await fetch(`/api${path}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    });
    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(await res.json());
    }
    else {
        return await res.json();
    }
};
```

Comment: res.json returns a promise because otherwise it would be blocking

Comment: `res.json()` returns a promise because `fetch` first resolves when the response *headers* have been read. At that point you can decide whether you also want to read the response body (which you'll need to await again) or not.

Comment: @deceze ah, I thought it resolves when *everything* has been received.

Comment: @blaumeise20 can I somehow merge the two outer `.then`'s? So if it's not an Error, just return the `res.json()`? Maybe `res.json().then(json => res.json())`?

Comment: @blaumeise20 is the `json => throw new Error(json)` a new feature? My IDE says it expects an operand, and npm says `Support for the experimental syntax 'throwExpressions' isn't currently enabled`.

Comment: `await fetch(...).then()` still looks terribly clumsy and messy to me (see my comment above). Why not go full `await`?

Comment: @sbrattla That is actually a new feature. Sorry, I'll update it.

Comment: @JeremyThille could you post an answer of how that could look? I haven't worked much with this, and have to admit I don't have a solid understanding of my possibilities here...

Comment: @blaumeise20 for the two first examples, i understand it still is a `Promise` that is being returned for `res.json()`? However, what happens to the `Error`. Is that also somehow wrapped in a `Promise`?

Comment: Sure, I posted an answer

Comment: @sbrattla if an error gets thrown inside a promise or async function (an async function always returns a promise) the promise will get rejected. Do you mean that?

Answer (score 1):

Using only the `await` syntax :

```
const postDataToAPI = async path => {

    try {
        const res = await fetch(`/api${path}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        });
        
        const data = await res.json();
        return data;
        
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("Error!", err)
    }
};
```